# Oracle 12c - Installing SW with an Active Directory Account on RHEL7

Tags: oracle, active-directory

My client insists on installing Oracle using an Active Directory Account as the SW owner instead of creating a local oracle service account on RHEL7.

I'm opposed, but willing to be flexible to meet their security and UID concerns.

Has anyone done this successfully?  Any Caveats?